# Como traer datos de una base de datos y pintarlos en react

Tags: reactjs

Buen día!

Alguien me puede decir como hago para traer los datos de una tabla en mi base de datos con react?

Soy nuevo en react y quiero aprender asi que no se como funciona muy bien para traer los datos de una tabla llamada "def_clientes"

tengo mi tabla en react asi:

```
<table>
                 <thead>
                 <tr className="titlesRow">
                                    <th>
                                        <p>{this.props.value == 1 && "Id company"}</p>
                                        <p>{this.props.value == 2 && "Id contacto"}</p>
                                        <p>{this.props.value == 3 && "Id Freelace"}</p>
                                        <p>{this.props.value == 4 && "Id colaborador"}</p>
                                    </th>
<tbody>


                                    <tr>
                                        <td>iddef_cliente</td>
                                        <td>razon_social</td>
                                        <td>nombre_comercial</td>
                                        <td>sitio_web</td>
                                        <td>email</td>

                                    </tr>
</tbody>
              </table>
```

Pero no tengo idea de como hacer que las columnas muestren lo que hay en mi tabla de la base de datos.

De esta manera mando a llamar un api.

```
getTable() {
CleverRequest.get(CleverConfig.getApiUrl('profile')+'/profile/search/',(response, error) => {
    if (!error) {
        $('.modal').modal();
        if(response != null) {
            this.Table.setData(response);
            $('#profile_modal').modal('open');
        }
    } else {
        console.error(response);
    return;
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hola Luis, creo que puedes tener una mezcla de conceptos y funcionamiento de las aplicaciones web. Te recomiendo informarte un poco más acerca del funcionamiento de `react` para que aprendas de qué forma delegarle funciones con los datos que provienen de tu base de datos y de tu backend. Del mismo modo, informarte acerca de como renderizar una lista de datos con `reactjs`

Comment: Es preciso que sepas diferenciar entre Frontend y Backend. React solo funciona del lado del frontend, lo que significa que si quieres consumir datos desde una base de datos, necesitas algún lenguaje como PHP o JAVA para poder  gestionar tu backend. También puedes utilizar firebase de google; aquí podrás montar un backend en unos cuantos pasos. Pero como mencionas que tienes tu propia base de datos, necesitarás aprender PHP, o adaptar tu base de datos para poder ser utilizada en algún servicio como firebase. Suerte.

Comment: Bueno creo que no me explique bien lo que puse es como referencia. en la parte de las columnas no tengo nada ya que quiereo que sea dinamico y es la parte que no se como hacerla

Answer (score 2):

Ya que tienes creada tu API necesitas consumirla desde REACT y existen varios métodos, fetch api que viene con EMS6 o axios

Un ejemplo con axios seria lo siguiente

```
axios.get('tu ruta')
  .then((response) => {
    return response;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: El OP. Ha modificado su pregunta por favor te invito a editar tu aporte para orientarlo a una respuesta a su duda